# Как сделать google Oauth 2.0 Angular 2+?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

вообщем есть такое пособие. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/O... По мимо него я еще очень много других нашел, но у меня в корне не получается после обратного редиректа(когда я попадаю на свой домен обратно после успешной логинки на странице гугла) получить данные чтоб дальше отправить по своему api accessToken.
Различные модули не предлагать. Я через них уже делал, и через firebase тоже. firebase слишком долго грузится, а другие модули работают через модалку, а мне нужно только через редирект. Всегда либо приходит false, либо вообще ничего не приходит, может я что то не так делаю?

```
//head
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

//myComponent
BtnClick(){
    window.location.href = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=*******&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=https://dm.devmarine.pp.ua&state=*****';

}

onInit(){
      gapi.load('client', () => {
      console.log('loaded');
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: ********,
        clientId: ********,
        scope: 'profile'
      });

      console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
      console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
}
```

Comment: тебе не нужно вручную прописывать URL, при инциализации клиента можно указать `ux_mode: 'redirect'`, тем самым при вызове `signIn()` гугл сам тебя будет редиректить на нужный урл

Comment: и также указываешь `redirect_uri: location.origin`, тем самым гугл тебя вернет обратно после успешной авторизации

Comment: после успешной авторизации гугл нужную ему информацию сохранит в куках и при повторном посещении страницы нужно вызывать `getAuthInstance().currentUser.isSignedIn().get()`

Comment: и аксес токен тебе тоже не нужен, вся информация о пользователе уже есть в свойстве `currentUser.get().getBasicProfile()`

Comment: а все остальное я правильно делаю? инициализация приложения gapi.load => init??? После init then нужен или можно без него?

Comment: да чувак, все нужно, либа сама по себе асинхронная

Comment: у `getAuthInstance()` тоже есть метод `then` :) это псевдо-промис (не инстанс `Promise`), c async/await работать не будет

Comment: не спасли меня эти правки

Comment: 1)gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.isSignedIn().get() выдает ошибку gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(...).currentUser.isSignedIn is not a function

Comment: 2) console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()); выдает большой обьект с ключами Ay fba TTl и так далее. значит либа подключена 
3)console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get())  выдает false

Т.е. что бы я не делал, логинился или нет или чистил куки или заходил в гугл настройки и удалял приложение - ничего не помогает

Comment: опиши конкретнее свою задачу, эти правки - поверхностные, я не знаю твой код, как ты используешь объекты google-auth и тд. Твой вопрос очень абстрактный, давай конкретизируем его, опиши задачу и требования :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри, в данном контексте все очень сильно зависит от поставленной задачи. Например, у нас есть внутренние системы, которые привязаны к Google аккаунту и пользователь в принципе не может увидеть приложение пока не авторизуется.

Я тебе покажу, как это реализовано у меня, ты можешь просто взять код и переделать его под свои нужды, ибо здесь нет никаких лучших практик, только trade-off'ы.

Во-первых нам нужны определения типов для удобной работы с Google библиотеками:

```
yarn add -D @types/{gapi,gapi.auth2,gapi.plus}
```

К сожалению компилятор видит это просто как глобальный тип, но не как свойство `window`, для этого создаем файл `typings.d.ts` в папке `src` наравне с `main.ts`:

```
declare interface Window {
  gapi: typeof gapi;
}
```

Все, `gapi` нам доступно в свойстве `window`.

У меня есть `GapiService` который занимается инициализацией Google объектов:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMapTo, shareReplay, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class GapiService {
  private config: gapi.auth2.ClientConfig = {
    scope: 'profile',
    ux_mode: 'redirect',
    redirect_uri: location.origin
  };

  private googleAuthObject$ = this.loadGapiAuth2Library().pipe(
    mergeMapTo(this.initializeAuth2()),
    mergeMapTo(this.loadGapiPlusLibrary()),
    mergeMapTo(this.waitForTheGoogleAuthObjectInitializationComplete()),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  public getGoogleAuthObject(): Observable<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth> {
    return this.googleAuthObject$;
  }

  public signIn(): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.googleAuthObject$.pipe(mergeMap(googleAuth => googleAuth.signIn()));
  }

  private loadGapiAuth2Library() {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
      window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  private loadGapiPlusLibrary() {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
      window.gapi.client
        .load('plus', 'v1')
        .then(() => {
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
    });
  }

  private initializeAuth2() {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
      window.gapi.auth2.init(this.config).then(
        () => {
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
        },
        error => {
          observer.error(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private waitForTheGoogleAuthObjectInitializationComplete() {
    return new Observable<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth>(observer => {
      window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().then(
        googleAuth => {
          observer.next(googleAuth);
          observer.complete();
        },
        error => {
          observer.error(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

И так, давай поэтапно пройдемся по коду:

- `loadGapiAuth2Library` - загружаем `auth2` библиотеку
- `initializeAuth2` - инициализируем библиотеку с нашей конфигурацией, инициализация асинхронная
- `loadGapiPlusLibrary` - загружаем библиотеку для работы с Google Plus
- `waitForTheGoogleAuthObjectInitializationComplete` - ждем инициализации объекта GoogleAuth, это тоже асинхронно

В некоторых местах используется `then/catch`, но это псевдо-промис (не инстанс `Promise`), с `async/await` работать не будет.

`shareReplay(1)` кеширует результат выполнения операторов, то есть если 10 раз подписаться на `googleAuthObject$`, то 10 раз либы грузиться не будут.

Также у меня есть `GapiVerifierService`, который перед инициализацией приложения проверяет авторизован ли пользователь:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { GapiService } from './gapi.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class GapiVerifierService {
  constructor(private gapiService: GapiService, private authService: AuthService) {}

  public verify(): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.gapiService.getGoogleAuthObject().pipe(
      mergeMap(googleAuth => {
        const isSignedIn = googleAuth.currentUser.get().isSignedIn();

        if (isSignedIn) {
          this.authService.setUser(googleAuth);
          return EMPTY;
        }

        return this.gapiService.signIn();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Что внутри `AuthService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '~app/shared/types';

import { GapiService } from './gapi.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  public user$ = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

  constructor(private gapiService: GapiService) {}

  public signOut(): void {
    this.gapiService
      .getGoogleAuthObject()
      .pipe(mergeMap(googleAuth => this.signOutFromAllAccounts(googleAuth)))
      .subscribe(() => {
        window.location.href = window.config.landingAppHost;
      });
  }

  public setUser(googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth): void {
    this.user$.next(new User(googleAuth));
  }

  private signOutFromAllAccounts(googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
      googleAuth
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

У меня после выхода из системы пользователя редиректит на лендинг страницу, можешь пропустить это. Что в классе `User`?

```
export class User {
  public readonly id: string;
  public readonly name: string;
  public readonly email: string;
  public readonly imageUrl: string;
  public readonly givenName: string;
  public readonly familyName: string;

  private readonly profile: gapi.auth2.BasicProfile;

  constructor(googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) {
    this.profile = googleAuth.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();

    this.id = this.profile.getId();
    this.name = this.profile.getName();
    this.email = this.profile.getEmail();
    this.imageUrl = this.profile.getImageUrl();
    this.givenName = this.profile.getGivenName();
    this.familyName = this.profile.getFamilyName();
  }
}
```

Как я это использую при инициализации приложения? Очень просто, провайжу `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```
export function appInitializerFactory(
  gapiVerifierService: GapiVerifierService
): () => Promise<unknown> {
  return () => gapiVerifierService.verify().toPromise();
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [GapiVerifierService]
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Если у тебя в приложении авторизация только по клику на кнопку или еще какой-то другой кейс, то тебе нужно проделать почти все то же самое, только в отместку еще создать какой-то страж `AuthGuard` на определенные URL'ы, который будет проверять авторизован ли пользователь или нет.

Comment: спасибо на подробный ответ. отмечу решением. Вообщем задача заключалась - просто получить ассess token от гугла, а дальше я отправляю на свой бекенд и с ним работает бекенд. там по сути нужно было просто урл прописать и все, а в редиректе я в урле получаю нужный токен после логинки. Просто я его не видел потому что у меня редирект юри был domain.com/ а в роутинге было прописано с корня перенаправлять на /main-page . то есть я его просто напросто затирал. Но все равно спасибо, буду знать как пользоваться апи чтоб получать полные данные непосредственно от гугла

Comment: аксес токен ты можешь получить после редиректа от гугла но только через `URLSearchParams`, ибо он таким образом захардкожен

Comment: Я уже понял и сделал :) Но все же спасибо :) я походу изначально не в те дебри пошел